# Can someone help me understand this point equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi guys sorry I am new in this forum. I thought why not use some help. This is finding a coordinate for x, this formula is same for y and z. I am sorry if I posted in wrong forum.Here is my question.

Can someone explain me how $x - x1 = \lambda * (x2 - x)$ is equal to $x = (x1 + L * x2) / (1 + \lambda)$

Thank you in advance.

I am trying and I get $x =\frac{ (\lambda*x2 + x1)}{\lambda }$

Here is what I did:

**1)** $x - x1 = \lambda*(x2 - x)$
**2)** $x - x1 = \lambda*x2 - \lambda*x;$
**3)** $\lambda*x + x - x1 = \lambda*x2$
**4)** $2*\lambda*x - x1 = \lambda*x2$
**5)** $x = \frac{(\lambda*x2 + x1)}{2*\lambda}$ -Here i subtract denominator with nominator (?) 
**6)** $x = \frac{(\lambda*x2 + x1)}{\lambda}$

:( ... I am sorry this is probably stupid easy to you but I have no idea whats going on why I cant get  1+L in denominator

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Your question is unreadable and should be re-written using MathJax. There is a quick tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank I will fix now.

Comment: Recheck step **4)**: $\;Lx+x \ne 2 \cdot Lx\,$.

Comment: L * 2 * x? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @GoldSpark No, $\,L \cdot x + x = L \cdot x + 1 \cdot x = (L+1) \cdot x\,$. For example $\,3x+x=4x\,$ when $\,L=3\,$.

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOO Man I want to buy you ferrari now!! How did I not think of that... come on.... Thanks a lot man I really appreciate it! Damn it! Can you tell me where I can find this on the internet to learn to do this myself in the future? I know this is logical but it didnt cross my mind once! What can I do to learn this best?

Comment: @GoldSpark You could start somewhere like [https://www.khanacademy.org/math/pre-algebra/pre-algebra-arith-prop](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/pre-algebra/pre-algebra-arith-prop), or maybe ask next door at [https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @GoldSpark : why do you keep posting using the tag "linear algebra" (you've done so with your other account too). This is high school algebra.

Comment: @amWhy No idea . Sorry if it offended you.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you man :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is elementary algebra.$$x-x_1=\lambda(x_2-x)=\lambda x_2-\lambda x$$ $$x+\lambda x=\lambda x_2+x_1$$  $$x(1+\lambda)=\lambda x_2+x_1$$ $$x=\frac{\lambda x_2+x_1} {1+\lambda}$$
Simple!

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. Thank you also for telling me area of mathematics now I am going to study this! :)